# Is it normal for the sight port of a water heater to ever have condensation in it?

Tags: water-heater

Is condensation in the sight port ever a "normal" occurrence?  Or does that mean the pan at the bottom is flooded.  I only see condensation, and it won't stay lit.

I called plumber out, and he said because water had gotten into the bottom of it (from flooding in my crawlspace), he would not light it because if it rusts gas could escape and be a liability.  He told me if I kept drying it out, though, it would eventually light.  He was right, and it did eventually light.

He also said the condensation in the sight port was because of the water.  I don't know if this answers it or not, but I will put it as such or delete the question.  Not sure what to do for this question.  I think the answer is "sort of" or maybe "not really."

Comment: Water vapor is a primary product of natural gas combustion. I wonder if you have an exhaust blockage. Does the unit have digital controls? (A model number would really help.)

Comment: No.  Just a regular Rheem gas water heater.  I have to find the model.  Hopefully, it will just start working.

Comment: Are you using the gas/pilot valve *correctly*? They are tricky and the procedure is not what you would expect.